# Difference between declaring a variable inside and outside a for loop function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning Python and was just practicing this problem. I need to create a function that performs an even-odd transform to a list, n times. Each even-odd transformation will:

Add two (+2) to each odd integer.

Subtract two (-2) to each even integer.

This is my code:

```
def even_odd_transform(lst, n):

    for i in range(n):
        o = 0  #declared inside the for loop

        while o < len(lst):
            if lst[o] % 2 == 0:
                lst[o] = lst[o] - 2
                o += 1
            else:
                lst[o] = lst[o] + 2
                o += 1
    return lst

even_odd_transform([0, 0, 0], 10)
```

Result:

```
[-20, -20, -20]
```

If I declared the 'o' variable outside the for loop function, I'll get the result = [-2,-2,-2]. Why can't it be [-20, -20, -20] instead?

Is there a concept I should be aware of such as global and local variables? If so, please do explain it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `o` outside the loop, you have forgotten to reset `o` to zero inside the loop. Your error has nothing to do with where `o` is declared. You have just forgotten to set your counter variable back to zero before the while loop.

**Edit:** Try printing the values in `1st` from within the for loop. You will see that if you do not reset the counter, the while loop is not called.

Comment: Oh, okay. But why should I reset the 'o' variable back to zero? After all, I'm trying to iterate it till the length of the list. Forgive me if this doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: @jelly_bean Perhaps I am misunderstanding your intent. Do you wish to iterate to the length of the list every time you pass through the for loop, or only the first time you pass through the for loop? If you want to iterate every time you go through the for loop, then you need to reset your counter.

Comment: Yes, I want to iterate it till the length of the list after each passing in the for loop. Can you explain why would I need to reset the counter?

Comment: @jelly_bean At the end of your first time through the for loop, the value of `o` is equal to `len(1st)`. So what is the value of `o` now when you enter the for loop the second time? If you did not reset it, then it is still `len(1st)`, and so you will skip the while loop entirely.